# MAUI Blazor - SCSS & Tailwind

Tags: visual-studio, sass, gulp, tailwind-css, maui-blazor

We have a .NET MAUI Blazor application with many Blazor pages.
Instead of pure CSS we use SCSS and Tailwind. We were searching how to fully automate transpilation to normal CSS (even in pipelines). At first we used [AspNetCore.SassCompiler](https://github.com/koenvzeijl/AspNetCore.SassCompiler) extension which was quite okay for scss but later we were missing `autoprefixer` functionality. We found out that this is exactly the reason why Task runners were implemented to VS. So we were deciding between:

- `Grunt`
- `Gulp`
- `Npm`
- `WebPack`

`Grunt` and `Gulp` are built into VS (others are 3rd party with many github issues). After some research we decided to use Gulp because it allows parallel compilation.

But to be able to run there some tasks each of our programmers have to install `nodejs` and also required packages we used inside gulp tasks by running `npm install`. These packages are specified in `package.json` in our `src` directory.

Questions:

- Is this the preferred flow how to compile SCSS and Tailwind ?
- Is there a way how to remove those manual steps for newcomers ? So they dont have to manually install `nodejs` and run `npm install` ?
- Are there any potential problems present in our configs below ?

PS: This is how our `package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "cssnano": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

and what our `gulpfile.js` contains

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');

// Sass source and destination
const sassSrc = 'wwwroot/style/scss/**/*.scss';
const sassDest = 'wwwroot/style/css';

//// Tailwind source and destination
const tailwindSrc = 'wwwroot/style/tailwind/**/*.css';
const tailwindConfig = 'wwwroot/style/tailwind/tailwind.config.js';
const tailwindDest = 'wwwroot/style/css';

// Define common function for compiling Sass, adding prefixes, and minifying
gulp.task('build-sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(sassSrc) // Gets all files ending with .scss in src/scss and children dirs
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // Initialize sourcemap
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError)) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()])) // Adds vendor prefixes with Autoprefixer
        .pipe(cleanCSS({ compatibility: 'ie10+' })) // Minifies the CSS
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Write the sourcemaps to the same dir
        .pipe(gulp.dest(sassDest));
});

gulp.task('build-tailwind', function () {
    return gulp.src(tailwindSrc)
        .pipe(postcss([
            tailwindcss(tailwindConfig),
            autoprefixer,
            cssnano()  // Tailwind minification
        ])) // Transpile Tailwind CSS
        .pipe(gulp.dest(tailwindDest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(sassSrc, gulp.series('build-sass'));

    const tailwindFiles = [
        "./../tailwind/*.*",
        "./../../../**/*.{razor,html,cshtml}",
        "./../../js/**/*.{js}",
    ];
    gulp.watch(tailwindFiles, gulp.series('build-tailwind'));
})

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('build-sass', 'build-tailwind'));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', 'watch'));
```

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.